# Single RDP session and automatic disconnect of pending session group policy not working in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy, virtual-machines, remote-desktop-services

Good morning,

I'm working on a client's environment. 
The servers are all Windows Server 2012.
There's a pool of virtual desktops which is used by users to connect to their virtual machines and perform work, currently stored in a VDI server.
There's also  a connection broker server which allows users to use RemoteApps.

I've set up a group policy object linked to the OU which relies to the VDI pool which sets the RDP session to just one per user, defines an automatic disconnection of inactive sessions after 6 hours, kills disconnected sessions after two hours and terminates the session when time limits are reached.

The client says that even if the GPO object is correctly applied, some users have multiple session residing in the connection broker server which handles the RDP connections, while the VDI pool shows that there's just one.

What's wrong with this configuration?

Best regards to all those who will help me.

Answer (score 0):

The "One Session per User" setting is a per-server setting, which prevents users from opening up multiple sessions on *the same host*. This is applied on reboot and restricts *one* sever only.

If you want to use this on all your session hosts:

1. Setup an NLB cluster for the servers.
2. Set up your Broker
3. Enable the setting "Restrict Terminal Services users to a single remote session" in the GPO that applies to all those servers.

These things together will restrict your connections.